# How to avoid code repetition for 3 similar buttons in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 buttons for 3 different languages,

User can choose on which language text will be present:

1. "DE german"
2. "FR french"
3. "En english"

```
// This is state of component:
 state = {
    translationOptions: {
      german: false,
      french: false,
      english: true
    }
  };

// This is function which change the language

  <button
    className={`doc-translation-btn ${german ? 'active-background-color' : ''}`}
    onClick={() => this.changeDocumentLanguage('german')}
  >
     DE
  </button>

  <button
    className={`doc-translation-btn ${french ? 'active-background-color' : ''}`}
    onClick={() => this.changeDocumentLanguage('french')}
    >
      FR
   </button>

  <button
     className={`doc-translation-btn ${english ? 'active-background-color' : '' }`}
     onClick={() => this.changeDocumentLanguage('english')}>
       EN
   </button>
```

How to optimize this code?

Comment: How about creating a function to loop over the translationOptions and generate each button dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const langs = [{name: 'German', abbr: 'GE'}, {name: 'French', abbr: 'FR'}, 
{name: 'English', abbr: 'EN'}]


//// Assuming React Stateful Component

state = {
   translationOption: ''  //Will be of of German, French, or English on state change
}

////

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {langs.map(({ name, abbr }) => (
          <button
            className={`doc-translation-btn ${name === 
            this.state.translationOption ? 'active-background-color' : '' }`}
            onClick={() => this.setState({ translationOption: name })>
           {abbr}
         </button>
        )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Note:** If you'd like to handle the applicable translation language in state with separate boolean properties -- whether nested or otherwise -- you need to account for switching other properties to false when another is set to true in your state handler method (assuming only one translation may apply at a time). Method like this could work:

```
  handleLangChange = selectedLang => {
    const { translationOptions: oldOpts } = this.state;
    const translationOptions = Object.keys(oldOpts).reduce((acc, cur) => {
       return { ...acc, [cur]: cur === selectedLang };
     }, {})

     this.setState({ ...this.state, translationOptions });
   }
```

Comment: This way doesn't not manages the short form of languages. `EN,FR,DE`

Comment: Apologies for that oversight - fixed :)

Comment: Huh? The comparison is there, and has been there prior to your note

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function `renderButtons` in which you create array of objects and then `map()` it to buttons.

```
renderButtons(){
   let btns = [
        {name: 'german', short: 'DE'}
        //... same for others.
   ]
   return btns.map(({name, short}) => (
      <button
    className={`doc-translation-btn ${this.state.translationOptions[name] ? 'active-background-color' : ''}`}
    onClick={() => this.changeDocumentLanguage(name)}
  >
     {short}
  </button>
   ))
}
```

And in the `render()` method just call this method where you want buttons.

```
render(){
    return (
       <div>{this.renderButtons()}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use array:

```js
const langDef = [
  { key: 'german', label: 'DE' },
  ...
]

const buttons = langDef.map(({ key, label })=>
  <button
    className={`doc-translation-btn ${this.state.translationOptions[key] ? 'active-background-color' : ''}`}
    onClick={() => this.changeDocumentLanguage(key)}
  >
     {label}
  </button>
)

return <div className="my-awesome-language-selector">{buttons}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the usecase you could also create a new Component for that:

```
 const LangButton = ({ active, name, abbr }) =>
  <button className={`doc-translation-btn ${active ? 'active-background-color' : ''}`}  onClick={() => this.changeDocumentLanguage(name)}>{abbr}</button>;

 return <div>
   <LangButton active={german} name="german" abbr="DE" />
   ...
 </div>;
```